# All content is unclickable inside bootrstrap `row`

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I create cards on API response with this function:

```
function createCard(name, img, description) {
$('#result').append(`
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="card" style="height: 200px; border: 2px solid black; border-radius: 5px; overflow: hidden; padding: 15px; margin: 15px 0;">
      <div class="card-content" style="height: 100%; overflow: hidden;">
        <div class="star" style="height: 1.6em;">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty pull-right"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="image col-xs-4" style="margin-top: 10px;">
            <figure style="height: 120px;">
              <img src=${img} alt="" style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%;">
            </figure>
          </div>
          <div class="description col-xs-8">
            <h4>${name}</h4>
            <p>${description}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  `);
}
```

And here is the `result` block:

```
<div id="result" class="row"></div>
```

And here is the jquery event handler:

```
$('.star').on('click', function() {
  console.log("!")
});
```

The problem is that there's no console log not only with `star` block but with any other inside the `result` block while it's ok with the `result` itself.

By the way, it's absolutely fine to apply hover pseudo class styling on `star` element which works just perfectly good. So, I can see how a glyphicon changes it's color on hover but it doesn't respond on click event.

So, my question is why all the content inside bootstrap `row` class is unclickable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your content is loaded dynamically. So you need to delegate the events to a static parent.

```
$(document).on('click', '.star', function() {
  console.log("!")
});
```

As above example, please use a static parent and not `document`. Use `document` when there's no static parent.

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '.star', function() {
    console.log("!")
  });
});

function createCard (name, img, description) {
  $('#result').append(`
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="card" style="height: 200px; border: 2px solid black; border-radius: 5px; overflow: hidden; padding: 15px; margin: 15px 0;">
      <div class="card-content" style="height: 100%; overflow: hidden;">
        <div class="star" style="height: 1.6em;">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty pull-right"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="image col-xs-4" style="margin-top: 10px;">
            <figure style="height: 120px;">
              <img src=${img} alt="" style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%;">
            </figure>
          </div>
          <div class="description col-xs-8">
            <h4>${name}</h4>
            <p>${description}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  `);
}

createCard ("Hello World 1!", "//placehold.it/100", "Hello World 1!");
createCard ("Hello World 2!", "//placehold.it/100", "Hello World 2!");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result" class="row"></div>
```

The `console.log` works when I click on the above snippet:

[image: console]

Comment: Yes, it works with `result` as parent. Thank you much, @Soolie. So you say the problem is with dynamic content loading. But I thought that DOM always rerenderes when changes like that happen. Then why page is unaware of changes in such cases?

Comment: @IgorChernega Because the JS event handler is not attached to the dynamically formed elements, as it is only with the already existing elements when the script is called.